stretch a parabolic velocity profile from a circle to an ellipse
The left figure shows a circle of radius a; it is actually the cross section of a liquid jet, which cross section is normal to flow.  The velocity profile of liquid within the jet is parabolic and is given by the following equation,
$$u =u_{max}(1-(r/a)^2)$$
where $u$ is the velocity, $u_{max}$ is the maximum velocity which occurs along the axial line of the jet (or for the cross section at the center point), a is the radius of the circular jet and r is some radial distance within the jet. The dashed concentric circles identify points in which the velocity, $u$, is constant per the equation.
Now what I would like to do is to rewrite the equation for an ellipse (right figure), which is the circle in the left figure that is stretched in only one direction so b> a.  How do I modify the equation to apply to this ellipse?


Substitute $r/a$ with $r/r(\theta)$, where $r(\theta)$ is the Polar form relative to center.

HINT:
$$\frac{u}{u_{max}}= 1-\frac{r^2}{a^2}\tag1$$
Use ellipse equation in polar coordinates from cartesian
$$ \frac{x^2}{b^2}+ \frac{y^2}{a^2}=1$$
$$ x= r \cos \theta,y= r \sin \theta~$$
$$ \frac{1}{r^2}=\frac{\cos^2 \theta}{b^2} +\frac{\sin ^2\theta}{a^2}$$
$$ \frac{a^2}{r^2}=\frac{a^2\cos^2 \theta}{b^2} +{\sin ^2\theta} \tag2 $$
Plug in $\dfrac{r^2}{a^2}$ reciprocal from (1) to obtain $u$ in terms of $\theta$.

Based on the method you proposed, here is what I end up with:
$$\frac{u}{u_{max}} = 1-\frac{1}{\frac{a^2}{b^2} \cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta}$$
The issue I'm having is that this doesn't seem to work for intererior concentric ellipses, whereas the eqn for the circle does.  With this equation for the ellipse, how do I get $u = u_{max}$ at the very center (shouldn't it be equal to $u_{max}$ or is that no longer the case.

Even for a circle $a=b$, it does not seem to work, as $u=0$ for all $\theta$.  Somewhere not right.
